# excel or php formula add fees when invoice delay every 5 month

Tags: php, excel

I'm trying to solve my issue in excel and php, i want to add fees every 5 months if customer delay to pay his invoice..

here is the formula example.. we have 3 tranche in every year..

**Date1**: 1/1/2020

**date2**: 2/10/2021

now, every 5 months we add 15% fees, normal price is 100$.

```
t1 = 100 + (100 * 15%) + (100 * 9 * 0.5%) = 
t2 = 100 + (100 * 15%) + (100 * 6 * 0.5%) =
t3 = 100 + (100 * 15%) + (100 * 3 * 0.5%) =
t4 = 100 + (100 * 15%) + (100 * 0 * 0.5%) =
```

the problem is how to calculate to get the number of month **9,6,3,0** between the two date...

```
$date1 = "2020-01-01";
$date2 = "2021-02-10";
$diff = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1));
$years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
$months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
```

i want to get the number of month and check if it's more than 5 month, we add 15% else continue... i think i need to have for loop (loop 4 times since we have 4 tranche), please if someone can help, i tried many times but not working...

if someone can help me in excel or php , if i get one logic, i will transform code not problem..

thanks in advance..

**UPDATED**

What I mean by 9,6,3,0

here is the example.

Suppose we have two dates: **1/1/2020** - **2/10/2021**

the invoice should be paid in **4/1/2020** if not, we add 15% fees in the next month **5/1/2020**.

Now, if we count from **6/1/2020** to **2/10/2021** so, the difference between the last dates is **9**

again, we calculate with the same way, we will get 6, then again 3, then again 0, so it's 4 tranche...

I think if we get the first number 9, we can always minus by 3.

```
9-3 = 6
6-3 = 3
3-3 = 0
```

hope it's clear now!

**UPDATED 2**

1/1/2020 - 10-02-2021

```
Months:
1-2-3            4-5-6            7-8-9           10-11-12


1 2 3 4
month 5 = 15%
count from month 6 to month 2
result 9;

4 5 6 7
Month 8 = 15%
count from month 9 to month 2
result 6;

7-8-9-10
Month 11 = 15%
count from month 12 to month 2
result 3;

10-11-12-01
Month 02 =15%
count from month 3 to month 2 (not
possible since date end in 10-02-2021
result 0;
```

**Total is 9+6+3+0= 18**

So, the formula will be:

$total_to_pay = 100 + (100 * 15%) + (100 * 18 * 0.5%);

Hope now it's clear..

Answer (score 0):

For PHP:

```
//difference in dates
    $interval = $date1->diff($date2);
    if($interval > 5)
    {
      if($interval>0 && $interval<3)
       {
         $amountNew = (($oldAmount * 0.15)+$oldAmount) + ($oldAmount *0 * 0.005);
       }elseif($interval>3 && $interval<6) //repeat these steps for all the intervals
        {
          $amountNew = (($oldAmount * 0.15)+$oldAmount) + ($oldAmount *3 * 0.005);
        }
          
    }
```

The above should do the trick for getting the date difference and adding the 15% to the amount. If you are storing the values in a DB, loop through it with a for loop or foreach.

for Excel:
use the following formula: `Datedif(cellofdate1; cellofdate2; "m")` this will give you the difference in months
the you can wrap it in an if

```
IF(DATEDIF(DATE1;DATE2;"M")>5;IF(DATEDIF(DATE1;DATE2;"M")=3;((AMOUNT*0,15)+AMOUNT) + (AMOUNT*3*0,005);E1)
```

Comment: thanks so much for quick reply, but formula not respected, where is 0.5% ?? i tried the example but now work.. do you think how to calculate to get the number of month 9,6,3,0 between the two date... it will help to calculate the fees, this is only the problem i have...how to get those numbers.. ?

Comment: so you said that you add a 15% (0.15) after every 5 months, so this check the difference in dates every 5 months and adds the percentage to it.
if you want to calcualte difference between the start date and the current date in 3 month periods just replace the 5 with a 3 and repeat them for 6 and 9

Comment: from my understand there is a start date and you need to do a check if 5 months has passed, if the current date is more than 5 month you add the 15% to the cost.so what you can do is an else if ill update my answer to do this

Comment: the problem is here, how did you know it"s 3 $oldAmount *3 * 0.005 and not 9.. I will update my question in few minutes to explain to you in details.. Thanks.

Comment: I've updated my answer, please check now!! thanks so much for trying to help me!

Comment: please check my update 3, it' now clear and easy to understand. Thanks!